# Как работать со списком в js

Tags: javascript

и так, у меня есть

```
// module.addListProperty(String: key, String: name, String: defaulfValue, String acceptedValues...)
// var move = module.getProperty(String: key);
// var value = move.getBoolean or getString or getList or getDoubleValue or getFloat or getInteger or getLong

module.addListProperty("Movement","Move","+X -X", "+X -X", "+Z -Z")
var move = module.getProperty("Movement").getList();
```

она создаёт список, где можно выбрать `+X -X` или `+X -X` всё выбрать, ничего не выбирать
[image: тут ничего не выбрано]
[image: выбрано что то]
[image: выбрано всё]

так вот, мне нужно сделать проверки
если выбрано `+X -X` то выполнять

```
client.print("Выбрано направление +X -X")
```

если выбрано `+Z -Z` то выполнять

```
client.print("Выбрано направление +Z -Z")
```

если выбрано всё, то

```
client.print("Выбраны все направления")
```

если ничего, то

```
client.print("Нету направления")
```

вот что возвращает `module.getProperty("Movement").getList();`

```json
// Выбрано направление +X -X
[+X -X]

// Выбрано направление +Z -Z
[+Z -Z]

// client.print("Выбраны все направления")
[+X -X, +Z -Z]

// Нету направления
[]
```

документация [тут](https://novoline.gitbook.io/novoscript/api/module#module.addlistproperty)

Comment: проверь какие свойства есть в том, что вернет `getList`. Есть ли свойство `length` чтобы можно было проверить количество элементов, можно ли обратиться к элементам по индексу? Есть ли какие-либо методы, аналогичные методам массива в javascript

Comment: его нету (length), в самом низу я написалто что возвращает getList @Grundy

Comment: не, это ты показываешь, как тебе выводится. Какие методы у полученного объекта есть - неизвестно. просто попробуй вывести что-то вроде `module.getProperty("Movement").getList().length` или `module.getProperty("Movement").getList()[0]` возможно есть какие-то стандартные методы получения свойств

Comment: сейчасс @Grundy

Comment: а, да, выводит [1], [2] и [0] @Grundy

Comment: попробуй вызвать `Array.isArray(list)` и посмотреть что выведется

Comment: не понял, тоесть `Array.isArray(module.getProperty("Movement").getList().length)`?

Comment: `Array.isArray(module.getProperty("Movement").getList())` - нужно проверить, а не обычный ли массив тебе просто приходит. Если конечно есть функция `Array.isArray` :)

Comment: возвращяет всегда `False` @Grundy

Comment: попробуй сделать цикл `for(var key in module.getProperty("Movement").getList()) { /* вот тут надо вывести key */ }` и добавь в вопрос что именно вывело

Comment: не работает должныйм образом, выводит либо 0 либо 1

Comment: ну тогда только вручную проверяй: если length = 0 - ничего не выбрано, если 2 - сразу два выбрано, если 1 - то берешь по 0 индексу элемент и сравниваешь с твоими строками `+X -X` либо `+Z -Z`. Возможно есть какие-то функции проверяющие вхождение типа `includes` или `contains` - но их можно не угадать

Comment: я понял то что оно возвращяет параментры в виде словаря, тоесть [1,2,4,5,6], можно ли это в js как-то считать? или типо того @Grundy

Comment: Не понял вопрос _можно ли это в js как-то считать?_ Тебе возвращается какая-то коллекция, ты знаешь сколько элементов в этой коллекции и можешь обратиться к конкретному элементу по индексу

Comment: допустииииим, не одно из вариантов не помогло( @Grundy

Comment: добавь в вопрос то что ты делал, и какой результат ты получил